# Payfast Payment Integration Flutter

Tags: flutter, payment-gateway, payfast

I am Implementing a payfast payment Integration, so I created a form where a user fills in amount and item name, I then want to send those details with the http call to the Payfast payment page to be shown on the Webview. So now, when I press the pay button, It does not navigate or show the webview and there are no errors. Please someone help me how to achieve this with my code below

Please check my code below:

```
class PayfastPayment extends StatefulWidget {
  PayfastPayment({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PayfastPaymentState createState() => _PayfastPaymentState();
}

class _PayfastPaymentState extends State<PayfastPayment> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> formstate = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController amountController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController itemNameController = TextEditingController();
  PaymentViewModel? model;
  var client = http.Client();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(centerTitle: true, title: const Text("Payment Page")),
      body: Form(
        key: formstate,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              controller: amountController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Amount',
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 100,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: itemNameController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Item Name',
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 220,
              height: 100,
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  print(
                      "Amount: ${amountController.text} Item: ${itemNameController.text}");
                  model?.payment(
                      amountController.text, itemNameController.text);
                },
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: const Center(
                      child: Text("Pay",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.white))),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  WebViewPageState createState() => WebViewPageState();
}

class WebViewPageState extends State<WebViewPage> {
  PaymentViewModel? model;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Web View"),
        ),
        body: Column(children: [
          Expanded(
              child: WebView(
            initialUrl: model?.payFast,
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onPageFinished: _onUrlChange,
            debuggingEnabled: true,
          ))
        ]));
  }

  _onUrlChange(String url) {
    print('Page finished loading: $url');
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        if (url.contains("http://localhost:8080/#/onSuccess")) {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/onSuccess");
        } else if (url.contains("http://localhost:8080/#/onCancel")) {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/onCancel");
        }
      });
    }
  }
}

class PaymentViewModel {
  TextEditingController amountController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController itemNameController = TextEditingController();
  API? api;
  String? errorMessage;
  String? payFast;

  void payment(String? amount, String? item_name) {
    //amount = amountController.text;
    item_name = itemNameController.text;
    api
        ?.payFastPayment(amount: amount, item_name: item_name)
        .then((createdPayment) {
      if (createdPayment == null) {
        errorMessage = "Something went wrong. Please try again.";
      } else {
        payFast = createdPayment;
      }
      print("It reaches here");
    }).catchError((error) {
      errorMessage = '${error.toString()}';
    });
  }
}

class API {
  static String baseURL = 'https://sandbox.payfast.co.za';

  var client = new http.Client();

  Future<String> payFastPayment({
    String? amount,
    String? item_name,
  }) async {
    Map<String, String>? requestHeaders;

    final queryParameters = {
      'merchant_key': '46f0cd694581a',
      'merchant_id': '10000100',
      'amount': '$amount',
      'item_name': '$item_name',
      'return_url': 'http://localhost:8080/#/onSuccess',
      'cancel_url': 'http://localhost:8080/#/onCancel',
    };
    Uri uri = Uri.https(baseURL, "/eng/process", queryParameters);
    print("URI ${uri.data}");
    final response = await client.put(uri, headers: requestHeaders);
    print("Response body ${response.body}");
    if (response.statusCode == 200 ||
        response.statusCode == 201 ||
        response.statusCode == 203 ||
        response.statusCode == 204) {
      return response.body;
    } else if (response.body != null) {
      return Future.error(response.body);
    } else {
      return Future.error('${response.toString()}');
    }
  }
}

class OnSuccess extends StatelessWidget {
  const OnSuccess({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String route = 'onSuccess';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: const [
          Text(
            "This is on Success",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 33),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 15),
          Icon(
            Icons.check,
            color: Colors.green,
            size: 40,
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}

class OnCancel extends StatelessWidget {
  const OnCancel({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String route = 'OnCancel';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: const [
          Text(
            "This is on Cancel",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 33),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 15),
          Icon(
            Icons.close,
            color: Colors.red,
            size: 40,
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial url seems to be null. You have created an instance of paymentViewModel named model. And called it in initial url of webview. In paymentViewModel payFast is just a nullable string. So the url maybe null. Please check

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I have added href to the initial url and it still does not want to open the webview. I will paste the code in the next line

Comment: class PaymentViewModel {

  PayFast_Model? payFast;
  API? api;
  String? errorMessage;
  //String? payFast;

  void payment(String? amount, String? item_name) {
    item_name = itemNameController.text;
    api
        ?.payFastPayment(amount: amount, item_name: item_name)
        .then((createdPayment) {
      if (createdPayment == null) {
        errorMessage = "Something went wrong. Please try again.";
      } else {
        payFast = createdPayment;
      }
      print("It reaches here");
    
  }
}

Comment: can you add it to the question please? unable to read it from here